# CREATE LINKED TABLE not working with PreparedStatement

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, h2

I'm trying to run the following PreparedStatement:

```
final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE LINKED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + linkedName + "(?, ?, ?, ?, 'ROADS', ?)");
```

But when the debugger runs over the previous line I get the error:

> Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE LINKED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   ROAD_TABLE_LINKED(?,[*] ?, ?, ?, 'ROADS', ?)"; expected "string";
>   SQL statement: CREATE LINKED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   ROAD_TABLE_LINKED(?, ?, ?, ?, 'ROADS', ?) [42001-199]

Is it not possible to used PreparedStatement with CREATE LINKED TABLE?

Edit: It works fine if I use a normal statement and insert the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use parameters (`?`) in DDL commands in H2. You need to replace them with string literals.

```java
Statement s = connection.createStatement();
s.execute("CREATE LINKED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \""
        + linkedName.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"")
        + "\"('', '"
        + url.replaceAll("'", "''")
        + "', '"
        + user.replaceAll("'", "''")
        + "', '"
        + password.replaceAll("'", "''")
        + "', '"
        + schema.replaceAll("'", "''")
        + "', '"
        + table.replaceAll("'", "''")
        + "')");
```